# How to test wso2 apim performance

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed wso2am-4.0.0 in okd, with 2gw, 2cp, 2tm. I'm going to have a performance test for WSO2 API Manager, I got docs from [here](https://github.com/wso2/performance-apim/tree/4.0.0), but I don't know hot to config, can any one guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Although these scripts are in the public domain, they seems to be developed specifically to be used inhouse. Hence trying to use them may be an overkill. I would suggest you to look at Some of the test scenarios available in that repo and build your own test script to test your specific use cases.